# nodejs failure to load URL due to cross problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors

I am runing node.js  app; it   works fine and  the frontend is with angular.js
the problem  is that  I  get :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/api/data_history. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @

from this code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', properties.clientHost);

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: That's an expected result if you don't set the CORS headers. Looks to me like you're trying to access your API from a different host than your angular app is running on.

Comment: the same  host different port i  added  the code above for  my app.js  in  node  still  the same  problem

Comment: can you show us your client-side code. also, if possible, boil down both the server-and client-side code into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Different ports will do it as well - you'll have to define the allowed ports in your CORS headers. That said, if you're putting this in production, you should be using a reverse proxy to host this on a trusted port (80, 443).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using express.... Instead of doing manually, what about using this middleware: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors sometimes it is a simple solution

```
var sqlite3    = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db         = new sqlite3.Database('data/demodb02');
var express    = require('express');
var cors       = require('cors');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


db.serialize(function() {
    //db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counts (key TEXT, value INTEGER)");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensor (id INT PRIMARY KEY, sensor_type integer, data real)");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location (longitude real NOT NULL, latitude real NOT NULL, sensor_id  integer, PRIMARY KEY (longitude, latitude), CONSTRAINT id FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) REFERENCES sensor(id))");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_live (sensor_id INTEGER, sensor_data REAL, time time, CONSTRAINT id FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) references sensor(id) CONSTRAINT data FOREIGN KEY (sensor_data) references sensor(data))");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_history (sensor_id INTEGER, sensor_data REAL, time time, date date, CONSTRAINT id FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) references sensor(id) CONSTRAINT id CONSTRAINT data FOREIGN KEY (sensor_data) references sensor(data))");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client (login varchar(50), password varchar(50), user_id integer, sensor_id integer, CONSTRAINT id FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) references sensor(id))");


    // test //
    //db.run("INSERT INTO counts (key, value) VALUES (?, ?)", "counter", 0);
    db.run("INSERT INTO sensor (id, sensor_type, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 1, 4, 8);
    db.run("INSERT INTO sensor (id, sensor_type, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 2, 9, 4);
    db.run("INSERT INTO sensor (id, sensor_type, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 3, 7, 1);
    db.run("INSERT INTO sensor (id, sensor_type, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 4, 1, 15);
    db.run("INSERT INTO location (longitude, latitude, sensor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 50, 45, 1);
    db.run("INSERT INTO data_live (sensor_id, sensor_data, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 1, 8, "08:44");
    db.run("INSERT INTO data_history (sensor_id, sensor_data, time, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 1, 8, "08:45", "12/05/2015");
    db.run("INSERT INTO client (login, password, user_id, sensor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", "user", "user", 1, 1);

    // fin test //
});


// dynamically include routes (Controller)//
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function (file) {
  if(file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
      route = require('./controllers/' + file);
      route.controller(app, db);
  }
});
//include the rules engine files //

/*s.readdirSync('./rules').forEach(function (file) {
  if(file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
      route = require('./rules/' + file);
      //route.controller(app, db);
  }
});*/


app.listen(3000)

console.log("Submit GET or POST to http://localhost:3000/api");
```

Comment: thanks guys but   i used express  actually yes  and  i did  install  cors  in vain  the problem ..

Comment: sorry didn't understand your comment...  it is solved or after install the module the problem persist?

Comment: the problem persists,I said I already installed  cors module but nothing changed ..

Comment: could you please paste some code? I want to see how are you using the module and a route

Comment: this is the app.js i then  defined  controlles  in  a seaparate folders  : for the 5 tables  and  it works  fine  :

Comment: Please check my answer updated, removed the method you were using setting headers and applying the cors middleware  before the body parsers

Comment: didnt find  your answer sorry :/ where is it ?

Comment: just edited my original answer and included the code... check it above  also here : https://gist.github.com/edsadr/334335896c8a60918291